# Clustering : handling categorical data, should we pivot and scale?

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I'm a SQLServer DBA and in the new version of this tool, there are new features to integrate **R scripts** and use it easily with the DB objects. That sounds cool.

But to use that, we have to know a little bit about stats and data mining.
And it's quite hard to find friendly and readable documentation for newbies like me. So, I will ask for some best-practice about **clustering**.

I have a dataset with few hundreds records and with 5 features, both categorical and numerical.

Regarding categorical data, I have a few basic questions :

- how can I manage **categorical** data ? what I understood from articles found is that I can transform categorical data in boolean and "pivoting" it. If a have a column with categorical data (for instance with values 'a' or 'b'), creating to new columns like column_a and column_b with value 0 or 1 ?
- should I always **center / scale** this new column ?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I think the question can be broken down into multiple questions. Points 1&2 together, 3, 4, 5 together and the last one separately. :)

Comment: Indeed, let's just keep the categorical topic. (title and question have been rephrased)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a dissimilarity matrix first and then apply the clustering technique. Below link has many answer referring your point. Hope below will suffice for this:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24540/clustering-of-mixed-type-data-with-r